# How to add timestamp to variable in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a variable in Powershell

```
$cvm = "derp1"
```

my question is how do I appened date to it while assigning a new variable.

```
$name = $(cvm{get-date})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question Vegeta,

What you are after is the `+` operator which will combine two string.

```
$cvm = "derp1"
$name = $cvm + (Get-Date)
derp102/06/2019 08:51:53
```

If you want to add a space, you would do `$name = $cvm + " " + (Get-Date)`
Different formats can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-6

Combining two strings is fine, combining an integer and a string will convert the entire lot to a string.

E.G.

```
$int = 1 # Int32
$string = "hello" # String
$newVar = $int + $string # String
```

Comment: thank you for the quick tip. I had done some googling prior but if I'm asking this. the other questions I found where way over my head.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date into a string of your chosen date format,
and then concatenate the strings :)

```
$cvm = "derp1"
$name = $cvm + "-" + (get-date).ToString("d")
>> derp1-2/6/2019
```

"d" in this case is short date, you can choose whatever you like